# A plugin is overriding the attribute values that I am setting using functions.php

Tags: php, wordpress

I have to following code:

```
function my_custom_avatar($avatar, $id_or_email, $size, $default, $alt) {
    // Stuff that sets background
    $avatar = "<img src='{$avatar}' alt='{$alt}' style='{$background}' class='avatar test avatar-{$size} photo' height='{$size}' width='{$size}' />";
    return $avatar;
}
add_filter( 'get_avatar' , 'my_custom_avatar' , 10, 5);
```

This code above applies the `style` attribute with a background URL in most cases so it is working correctly.

However, on one page of the forum plugin, the `style` attribute is set to `width: 64px; height: 64px;`. It looks like my `style` attribute value was overridden by some other filter that the plugin is using for `get_avatar`.

Is there any way to make sure that the code added by my filter is not overwritten by the plugin?

I tried increasing the priority using:

```
 add_filter( 'get_avatar' , 'my_custom_avatar' , 99, 5);
 add_filter( 'get_avatar' , 'my_custom_avatar' , 999, 5);
 add_filter( 'get_avatar' , 'my_custom_avatar' , 9999999, 5);
```

However, none of them worked.

How can I prevent the plugin from overriding my values?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can delete filter created by plugin with `remove_filter`, for example if plugin is like:

```
function pluginMethod($args) {}
add_filter('get_avatar', 'pluginMethod', 10, 5);
```

You can do:

```
remove_filter('get_avatar', 'pluginMethod');
```

See: https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/remove_filter

Hope this help you.